# DataPager1 not found for a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datapager

I am trying to initialize the `DataPager` `SetPageProperties()` method but for an unknown reason I got this

> Error 'Appointement' does not contain a definition for 'DataPager1' and no extension method 'DataPager1' accepting a first argument of type 'Appointement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is the code

```
protected void ListView1_PagePropertiesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    indexDdl = Convert.ToInt32(Session["dentistId"]);

    int StartRowIndex = 0;
    int MaximumRows = 10;
    this.DataPager1.SetPageProperties(StartRowIndex, MaximumRows, true); <= error with DataPager1
    Appointement(indexDdl);  
}
```

Here is .aspx page

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" Autopostback="true" >
   <Fields>
      <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
           ShowLastPageButton="True" />
   </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
```

Any idea of why it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think 'this' can be used here. Does intellisense see DataPager1 when you hit '.' after 'this'?

Comment: I don't see an `Appointement` on the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DataPager DataPager1;
    DataPager DataPager1 = ListView1.FindControl("DataPager1") as DataPager;
```